# Where in the digestive tract are melatonin pills dissolved? Same question for gelatin capsules

Tags: human-anatomy, gastroenterology

I want to do a blind controlled experiment on myself to learn whether melatonin pills have any effects on me. I bought some empty gelatin capsules. I am going to fill some of them with rice and put pieces of melatonin pill in others.

[image: These are not melatonin pills, but the idea is the same]

Melatonin pills instruction says I should take it 30-40 minutes before going to bed. Now I wonder if the timing is the same when stuck inside gelatin capsules. Also is it possible that melatonin pills stuck inside capsules will get to a later stage of the digestive tract than they should and thus will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless specially coated or formulated, most pills break apart in the stomach. Note: "break apart", not necessarily *absorbed*.

Take a gelatin capsule with rice or melatonin and immerse it in warm water. Massage gently with your fingers. Watch the clock.

When the rice is fully exposed, or the melatonin starts to break apart and dissolve, add that amount of time to the instructions. Be sure to take it with at least 4 ounces of water.

Comment: Doesn't acid in the stomach help the capsule break apart faster?